# interp2d not handling proprely unordered inputs when used

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

Today Python bit me, with a behavior of `interp2d` I did not expect. I am used to `interp1d`, for instance, defining

```
f = interp1d(np.linspace(0, 1, 10), np.linspace(1, 2, 10), kind='linear')
```

we get an interpolator that is sensitive to the order of the arguments its called with. `f([0, 0.5, 1])` returns `array([1, 1.5, 2])` while `f([0.5, 1, 0])` returns `array([1.5, 2], 1)`. As I would expect.

However, with `interp2d` I'm getting something different. After defining

```
g = interp2d([0,1], [0,1], [[1,2], [2,3]], kind='linear')
```

the call `g([0, 0.2, 1], [0.3])` returns `array([1.3, 1.5, 2.3])`, but reordering the argument takes no effect. For instance, `g([0.2, 1, 0])` gives me exactly the same. Which is undesired. I find no traces of this in `interp2d`'s documentation, let alone an option to change this behavior.

I also tried and converted this example to `RectBivariateSpline`, the invocation raises an exception when the vector given is not ordered: `ValueError("Error code returnod by bispev: 10")`.

I could implement a wrapper around interp2d with `argsort`, so that it takes care of the order and corrects it afterwards. But I find hard to believe this is the way to go, would assume it is possible to get what I want as a given. Suggestions, please!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option `assume_sorted=False` in the interp2d's [call function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__). The corresponding code is:

```
if not assume_sorted:
    x = np.sort(x)
    y = np.sort(y)
```

So by default x and y and sorted before use. However, unlike `interp1d`, "x and y have to be arrays of monotonically increasing values.", thus setting `assume_sorted=True` leads to `ValueError: Invalid input data`. There is no choice but to perform the interpolation using ordered x and y.

[RectBivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.__call__) provides the choice "Whether to evaluate the results on a grid spanned by the input arrays, or at points specified by the input arrays."

For instance:

```
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

g = RectBivariateSpline([0, 1, 2], [0, 1],
                        np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]).T,
                        kx=1, ky=1)  # x, and y are reversed compared to interp2d

x = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1]
y = [0.2, ]
print(g(x, y)) # -> ValueError: Error code returned by bispev: 10

x = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1]
y = [0.2,]*len(x)
print(g(x, y, grid=False)) # -> [0.3 0.2 0.1]
```

Here the output is no more values on a 2D grid (2d array) but a list of values (1d array).

Comment: Perfect answer, I overlooked this in the documentation, because it is not an argument in the construction of the interpolator, it appears only in the call.